# Updated node memory size globally with commands, but now new memory size causing problems

Tags: node.js, memory, heap-memory

I needed to increase memory size globally because i was operating with a .ts file including over 150k+ JSON objects.

To serve and preview the project without any memory heap errors i used these commands to increase nodejs memory globally

```
npm install -g increase-memory-limit
```

and then

```
increase-memory-limit
```

so afterwards it applied and updated certain packages in /nodemodules/.bin directory but now i cannot serve & preview any project even if it has little memory usage.

I get this following error when i run -ionic serve

> ng.cmd run app:serve --host=localhost --port=8100
>   [ng] '"node --max-old-space-size=10240"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   [ng] operable program or batch file.

[ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 9009).

The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details.

---

i want to undo this memory increase operation or somehow try to make it work with 10240 mb rams. I have 16 gb ram but cant seem to make this memory usage increase in size. Can someone please help me with my case...

Answer (score 1):

the best thing to do is to delete the  **node_modules** folder and run `npm install` again

Answer (score 0):

the the following:

1. delete the node_modules
2. package.json add this script: "build": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build"
3. then execute: npm run build

** I was getting this error at run-time after upgrading to angular 9.